Do I need to close resources with dynamic datasource (Spring)
I need to dynamically create a datasource, jdbcTemplate and TransactionTemplate.
Should I somehow close datasource, jdbcTeplate and TransactionTemplate on my own, since I create them myself?
I am considering two options for creating:

The first option
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasources")
    public Map<String, DataSourceProperties> dataSourceProperties() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSources(Map<String, DataSourceProperties> dataSourceProperties) {
        Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceProperties.forEach((name, properties) -> {
            HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getUrl());
            dataSource.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName());
            dataSources.put(name, dataSource);
        });
        return dataSources;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, TransactionTemplate> transactionTemplates(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
        Map<String, TransactionTemplate> transactionTemplates = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.forEach((name, dataSource) -> {
            DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
            transactionTemplates.put(name, new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager));
        });
        return transactionTemplates;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplates(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
        Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplates = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.forEach((name, dataSource) -> {
            jdbcTemplates.put(name, new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
        });
        return jdbcTemplates;
    }

}


The second option
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasources")
    public Map<String, DataSourceProperties> dataSourceProperties() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSources(Map<String, DataSourceProperties> dataSourceProperties) {
        Map<String, DataSource> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceProperties.forEach((name, properties) -> {
            HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getUrl());
            dataSource.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName());
            dataSources.put(name, dataSource);
        });
        return dataSources;
    }


    @Bean
    public Map<String, DBManager> dbManagers(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
        Map<String, DBManager> dbManagers = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.forEach((name, dataSource) -> {
            DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
            dbManagers.put(name, new DBManager(dataSource, new JdbcTemplate(dataSource), new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager)));

        });
        return dbManagers;
    }

}

public class DBManager {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public DBManager(DataSource dataSource, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.transactionTemplate = transactionTemplate;
    }
///...
}




You only need to take care of closing the DataSource that you created. Normally this would be done by Spring automatically but as the datasources aren't really beans in this case that won't happen.
